# Угол поворота объекта

Tags: python

Вот код, который должен находить прямоугольник на фото и определять угол его поворота:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import math

hsv_min = np.array((0, 54, 5), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((187, 255, 253), np.uint8)

color_blue = (255, 0, 0)
color_yellow = (0, 255, 255)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fn = 'images/01.jpg'  # имя файла, который будем анализировать
    img = cv.imread(fn)

    hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)  # меняем цветовую модель с BGR на HSV
    thresh = cv.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max)  # применяем цветовой фильтр
    contours0, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # перебираем все найденные контуры в цикле
    for cnt in contours0:
        rect = cv.minAreaRect(cnt)  # пытаемся вписать прямоугольник
    box = cv.boxPoints(rect)  # поиск четырех вершин прямоугольника
    box = np.int0(box)  # округление координат
    center = (int(rect[0][0]), int(rect[0][1]))
    area = int(rect[1][0] * rect[1][1])  # вычисление площади

    # вычисление координат двух векторов, являющихся сторонам прямоугольника
    edge1 = np.int0((box[1][0] - box[0][0], box[1][1] - box[0][1]))
    edge2 = np.int0((box[2][0] - box[1][0], box[2][1] - box[1][1]))

    # выясняем какой вектор больше
    usedEdge = edge1
    if cv.norm(edge2) > cv.norm(edge1):
        usedEdge = edge2
    reference = (1, 0)  # горизонтальный вектор, задающий горизонт

    # вычисляем угол между самой длинной стороной прямоугольника и горизонтом
    angle = 180.0 / math.pi * math.acos(
        (reference[0] * usedEdge[0] + reference[1] * usedEdge[1]) / (cv.norm(reference) * cv.norm(usedEdge)))

    if area > 500:
        cv.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (255, 0, 0), 2)  # рисуем прямоугольник
        cv.circle(img, center, 5, color_yellow, 2)  # рисуем маленький кружок в центре прямоугольника
        # выводим в кадр величину угла наклона
        cv.putText(img, "%d" % int(angle), (center[0] + 20, center[1] - 20),
                   cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, color_yellow, 2)

    cv.imshow('contours', img)

    cv.waitKey()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Вот фотография, с которой работает код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при запуске программа просто выводит ту же самую картинку, не выделяя контуров и не выводя угол поворота, помогите как исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `_,` в начале строки, с какой-то версии возвращается 2 параметра, а не 3 и не нужно ничего отбрасывать.

Comment: программа стала запускаться, но теперь она просто выдаёт эту же картинку не определяя угол и не выделяя прямоугольник

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, всё что после `for cnt in contours0:` и до `cv.imshow` должно идти с отступом, это всё должно быть внутри цикла. А у вас внутри цикла только строка `rect = cv.minAreaRect(cnt)`. В результате вы работаете только с последним из найденных контуров и он, наверное, не попадает под критерии отрисовки. Но не факт, что дело только в этом.

Comment: Да, спасибо помогло!